# What is wrong with this HS256 token?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am using jwt-php and firebase-tokengenerator to create a token for custom auth flow (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-token-generator-php).

I continually get invalid_custom_token errors. Like this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"
 }
}
```

When I put my generated token into https://jwt.io/ I get 'invalid signature' **UNTIL** I manually change one character in the UID or displayName.

Here's a generated token that fails both the jwt.io site and Firebase when applied:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhZG1pbiI6ZmFsc2UsImRlYnVnIjpmYWxzZSwiZCI6eyJ1aWQiOiI2NTQwMDA0NCIsImRpc3BsYXlOYW1lIjoiV2lsbHkgRSBDb3lvdGUifSwidiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTE5ODUyNzE1fQ.ScM_nZtwH1zCyiWnPKNi_JLTVwguKibS5z8FLjo6Lco

But if I change one character it suddenly passes jwt.io. Which could be meaningless, but I'm at the end of my rope trying anything to get through this stupid step before I abandon the whole approach and try something else...

I use Firebase for Google and username/pw auth and am trying to connect a 3rd party auth system (LTI) to my project.

Here is the php:

```
$expires = time() + 3600;
$secret = 'XXXX';

try {
  $generator = new TokenGenerator($secret);
  $token = $generator
    // ->setOption('admin', false)
    // ->setOption('debug', true)
    // ->setOption('expires', $expires)
    ->setData(array('uid' => '65400044', 'displayName' => 'Willy E Coyote'))
    ->create();
} catch (TokenException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
echo $token;
```

And the jquery that uses the token:

```
success: function(fbToken){
  console.log('Response from FB token generator: ') + console.log(fbToken);
  console.log('Now try Firebase with token...');
  firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(fbToken).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log('Errors: ' + error.message);
    // ...
  });
```

I also don't understand why there are two calls to Firebase in the console. The first one doesn't result in data but is successful (200 code). The second one shows the error and 400.
[image: Console view showing 2 calls to Firebase]

I've ready about problems with IAT...and I also wonder if I've got all the necessary info to identify my Firebase project - the only data in the php script is the Firebase project secret.

Any help or direction appreciated...

Comment: jwt.io needs to know the secret which was used for the signature.There is an input field for it under Verify Signature. The verification fails when you don't provide the secret. When you change a value in the payload on the right side, you see the effect that the signature is verified. That because the debugger works in both directions, if you change something on the right side, it calculates a new signature with the given secret (default is "secret"). Just watch what happens on the left side, when you change the payload on the right side.

Comment: Thank you for responding to this question...and you are entirely correct that I was not understanding the tool completely.

Turns out that the token was legit, but it was for SDK 2...and the code trying to USE the token was SDK 3.

The correct way to generate a token for Firebase custom auth, if you want to use PHP on the back end, is with php-jwt and code like the example at the very bottom of this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens?authuser=0.

Answer (score 0):

As you already wrote in a comment to your original post, the issue was that you used a deprecated token generator which only works with database secrets, which have been deprecated by Firebase.

With the new SDK, you have to sign custom tokens with a private key generated for your project, which you can retrieve by downloading a credentials file from the [Service Accounts Section](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) in your project's settings.

In case you don't want to implement the flow yourself, I suggest having a look at https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php which allows you to work like this:

```
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile('/path/to/credentials.json');

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
    ->create();

$uid = 'some-uid';
$additionalClaims = []; // optional

$customToken = $firebase->getAuth()->createCustomToken($uid, $additionalClaims);
```

You can also verify ID Tokens created by your client application and more, as described at https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Disclaimer: I created the library :).